# var transporter is causing a webpack error and I have no clue why. I have the latest version of nodemailer

Tags: reactjs, webpack, nodemailer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, history } from 'react-router-dom'
import Footer from "./Footer"
import Menu from './Menu'
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet'
import Scroll from 'react-scroll'
import Validation from 'react-validation'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { ajax } from 'jquery'
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'
import smtpTransport from 'nodemailer-smtp-transport'


export default class Form extends Component {

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'gmail.user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'userpass'
    }
});


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Form: {
        Name: "",
        Email: "",
        Website: "",
        Subject: "",
        Message: ""
      }
    }
    this.onFormChange = this.onFormChange.bind(this)
  }

  onFormChange(e) {
    var formName = this._name.value
    var formEmail = this._email.value
    var formWebsite = this._website.value
    var formSubject = this._subject.value
    var formMessage = this._message.value
    console.log(formEmail);
    this.setState({
      Form: {
        Name: formName,
        Email: formEmail,
        Website: formWebsite,
        Subject: formSubject,
        Message: formMessage
      }
    })
  }


  onFormSubmit(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const formInputs = this.state.Form

    return(
      <section>
        <Validation.components.Form
          method="post"
          onChange={this.onFormChange}>
          <input
          ref={input => this._name = input}
            name="Name"
            type="text"
            placeholder="NAME" />
          <input
            ref={input => this._email = input}
            name="Email"
            type="text"
            placeholder="EMAIL" />
          <input
            ref={input => this._website = input}
            name="Website"
            type="text"
            placeholder="WEBSITE" />
          <input
            ref={input => this._subject = input}
            name="Website"
            type="text"
            placeholder="SUBJECT" />
          <textarea
            ref={input => this._message = input}
            name="Message"
            type="text"
            placeholder="MESSAGE" />
          <input onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)} type="submit"/>
        </Validation.components.Form>
        <p>{this.state.Name}</p>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
"nodemailer": "^4.1.0",
"nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
```

And here is the webpack error im getting.

```
ERROR in ./js/Form.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (26:6)

  24 | export default class Form extends Component {
  25 |
> 26 |   var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     |       ^
  27 |     service: 'Gmail',
  28 |     auth: {
  29 |         user: 'gmail.user@gmail.com',
```

I dont understand why this declared variable would cause this error.  I followed the nodemailer docs and have looked and looked but cant seem to find the reason this is happening. Been stick on this issue for a week.  I need help.  Thank you

Comment: This is because you can't `var` things directly inside a class like this. If you want a class property you can `transporter =` without the `var`.

Also make sure to transform class properties if you want this feature: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: As an aside, are you sure you can use nodemailer on the client? It looks like a nodejs package as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok I took out the var and that didnt work.  Im curious to the aside you mentioned.  How do I implement nodemailer with my react web app if its a node package?

Comment: You'd need to write a node program and talk to it via some interface (Like an HTTP API). You might do that by writing an expresJS app or an AWS Lambda function that you can talk to via API Gateway etc. If you're not experienced with this then it could be easier to talk directly to an email service like mailchimp.